# How to specify the iframe default icon view that has path to local HDD folder?

Tags: iframe, view, icons, default, local

I have an iframe that leads to a local disk folder, so that it works like a windows explorer. For e.g:

```
iframe name="Folder" width="1440" height="600" src="..\Media\Icons\OG\"
```

I've been using this as a personal file explorer for some of my PC for easy access to some programs/files, and I'm only executing this LOCALLY on my own computers since Windows XP, but lately I've migrated them all to Windows 7. The problem I am having now is that the iframe is showing the files/icons as "Details" view as default when it is loaded.

When running on Windows XP, the iframe shows the files/icons as "Tiles" if files are not that much, whereas if the destination folder is with many files, it will show them as "Icons"(now known as Medium icons in Win7). I haven't researched for it before because I think it's fine with either the "Tiles" or "Icons" but the "Details" view now it makes it unpractical and ugly. Anyone knows how to control this behaviour?